# Interop.Word can't use map template documents

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm I have created an application which looks at a word template and populates bookmarks within the template accordingly. Currently, this all works fine with no issues in my dev environment. I have now tried to move my application to a shared drive and I get an error trying to locate one of my word templates that is currently on a shared drive.

```
 Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Object oTemplatePath = null;

        if (Variables.Training)
        {
            oTemplatePath =ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Training"];
        }
        else if(Variables.Services)
        {
            oTemplatePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Services"];
        }
        else
        {
             oTemplatePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultPath"];
        }

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        wordApp.Visible = true;

        Document wordDoc = new Document();

        wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

I get an error at wordDoc = wordApp ...

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in
>   SOWBuilder.exe Additional information: Sorry, we couldn't find your
>   file. Was it moved, renamed, or deleted?

The mapped drive is a typical folder no funny characters and no spaces, I thought it was permissions but even if I run the application as administrator it gives me this error

Full Exception

```
     System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
     ErrorCode=-2146823114
     HResult=-2146823114
     HelpLink=wdmain11.chm#24654
     Message=Sorry, we couldn't find your file. Was it moved, renamed, or deleted?
     Source=Microsoft Word
     StackTrace:
    at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Documents.Add(Object& Template, Object& NewTemplate, Object& DocumentType, Object& Visible)
    at Builder.CreateSoW..ctor() in C:\Tools\Builder\Create.cs:line 47
    at Builder.MasterForm3.buttonNext_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Tools\Builder\MasterForm3.cs:line 245
    at Builder.MasterForm3.<.ctor>b__3_2(Object sender, EventArgs EventArgs) in C:\Tools\Builder\MasterForm3.cs:line 114
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
    at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
    at Builder.Program.Main() in C:\Tools\Builder\Program.cs:line 22
    InnerException:
```

Comment: are you sure that the user account under which this runs, has the same drive mapping? add a simple `File.Exists(oTemplatePath)` call to the code and see what it returns for the path.

Comment: Have you checked Office Security Center settings? is this network drive set as a trusted location? (File=>Security Center=>Trusted Locations)

Comment: @dlatikay This is a really good idea, thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I had used the path from Microsoft Word to find the template that is given when you go to File --> Info -->Copy Link to Clipboard. Using this link does not work if you have spaces in the file name as spaces contain '%20'.By removing the '%20' resolved my issue. Thanks for the responses